# FluentAssertions: How to compare two collections using a custom comparison on each pair of elements?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, assertion, fluent-assertions

Given the following inputs:

```cs
var customers = new[] {
    new Customer { Name = "John", Age = 42 },
    new Customer { Name = "Mary", Age = 43 }
};
var employees = new[] {
    new Employee { FirstName = "John", Age = 42 },
    new Employee { FirstName = "Mary", Age = 43 }
};
```

**What would be the best way to compare these lists using FluentAssertions?**

My only approach at the moment looks like this -- quite similar to [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netstandard-2.0):

```cs
using (var customerEnumerator = customers.GetEnumerator())
using (var employeeEnumerator = employees.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (customerEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        employeeEnumerator.MoveNext().Should().BeTrue();
        var (customer, employee) = (customerEnumerator.Current, employee.Current);

        customer.Name.Should().BeEquivalentTo(employee.FirstName);
        customer.Age.Should().Be(employee.Age);
    }
    employeeEnumerator.MoveNext().Should().BeFalse();
}
```

Of course, this is neither easy to read nor providing diagnostic outputs of FA's usual quality. Is there any FluentAssertions-built-in method to make this assertion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to improve the assertion would be to extract the comparison into a custom [`IEquivalencyStep`](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#equivalency-assertion-step-by-step) to guide how a `Customer` and an `Employee` should be compared.

It consist of two parts:

- `CanHandle` which determines when this comparison is applicable, and
- `Handle` to perform the custom comparisons.

```cs
public class CustomerEmployeeComparer : IEquivalencyStep
{
    public bool CanHandle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context,
        IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
    {
        return context.Subject is Customer
            && context.Expectation is Employee;
    }

    public bool Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator
        parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
    {
        var customer = (Customer)context.Subject;
        var employee = (Employee)context.Expectation;

        customer.Name.Should().Be(employee.FirstName, context.Because, context.BecauseArgs);
        customer.Age.Should().Be(employee.Age, context.Because, context.BecauseArgs);

        return true;
    }
}
```

To use `CustomerEmployeeComparer` in an assertion, add it by invoking `Using(new CustomerEmployeeComparer())` on the `EquivalencyAssertionOptions config` parameter of `BeEquivalentTo`.

Note: As your example requires the two lists to be compared in order, I've added [`WithStrictOrdering()`](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#ordering) to the example below.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void CompareCustomersAndEmployeesWithCustomEquivalencyStep()
{
    // Arrange
    var customers = new[] {
        new Customer { Name = "John", Age = 42 },
        new Customer { Name = "Mary", Age = 43 }
    };

    var employees = new[] {
        new Employee { FirstName = "John", Age = 42 },
        new Employee { FirstName = "Mary", Age = 43 }
    };

    // Act / Assert
    customers.Should().BeEquivalentTo(employees, opt => opt
        .Using(new CustomerEmployeeComparer())
        .WithStrictOrdering());
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Changing the name of the first `Employee` to Jonathan, now gives this failure message:

```
Message: Expected item[0] to be "Jonathan" with a length of 8, but "John" has a length of 4, differs near "hn" (index 2).

With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Include all non-private properties
- Include all non-private fields
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Without automatic conversion.
- UnitTestProject15.CustomerEmployeeComparer
- Without automatic conversion.
- Always be strict about the collection order
```

For anyone interested, there is a related open issue about overriding which properties to compare. 
https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535