# Fluent Assertions 6: Comparing two collections with different members types and names

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

In the previous versions of Fluent Assertions, there was a possibility to compare two collections with different members types and names by creating a class which implements `IEquivalencyStep`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55898570

Unfortunately, version 6 changed this interface and the trick does not work. Is there any workaround for this kind of comparison in the current version of Fluent Assertions?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this "trick" doesn't work anymore?

Also good to know that we're working on [first-class support](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535#issuecomment-961386728) for comparing different properties.

Comment: Interface IEquivalencyStep was changed: method CanHandle does not exist and method Handle has different signature.